# Convert list of tuples w/ lenght 5 to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

what if I have a tuple list like this:

```
list =  [('Ana', 'Lisbon', 42195, '10-18', 2224),
        ('Eva', 'New York', 42195, '06-13', 2319),
        ('Ana', 'Tokyo', 42195, '02-22', 2403),
        ('Eva', 'Sao Paulo', 21098, '04-12', 1182),
        ('Ana', 'Sao Paulo', 21098, '04-12', 1096),
        ('Dulce', 'Tokyo', 42195, '02-22', 2449),
        ('Ana', 'Boston', 42195, '04-20', 2187)]
```

How can I convert this to a dictionary like this one?

```
dict = {'Ana': [('Ana', 'Lisboa', 42195, '10-18', 2224),('Ana', 'Toquio',42195, '02-22', 2403), 
      ('Ana', 'Sao Paulo', 21098, '04-12', 1096),('Ana', 'Boston', 42195, '04-20', 2187)],
      'Dulce': [('Dulce', 'Toquio', 42195, '02-22', 2449)],
      'Eva': [('Eva', 'Nova Iorque', 42195, '06-13', 2319), 
      ('Eva', 'Sao Paulo', 21098, '04-12', 1182)]}
```

Comment: don't use dict/list as variable names

Answer (score 4):

You can just loop through the list like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
combined = defaultdict(list)
for i in list1:
  combined[i[0]].append(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lst =  [('Ana', 'Lisbon', 42195, '10-18', 2224),
        ('Eva', 'New York', 42195, '06-13', 2319),
        ('Ana', 'Tokyo', 42195, '02-22', 2403),
        ('Eva', 'Sao Paulo', 21098, '04-12', 1182),
        ('Ana', 'Sao Paulo', 21098, '04-12', 1096),
        ('Dulce', 'Tokyo', 42195, '02-22', 2449),
        ('Ana', 'Boston', 42195, '04-20', 2187)]

dct = {}

for tp in lst:
    if  tp[0] not in dct.keys():
        dct[tp[0]] = []
    dct[tp[0]].append(tp)
print dct
```